# VBA – print file name in each row until the file closes

Tags: vba, excel, filenames

I have a working macro that loops through folder to open files and get important info from the columns of names "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" and printing all the info to one excel document, masterfile.

It currently looks like picture 1. I would like it to print the file name in column one in every row until the file closes so that for every entry in columns 2 and 3, there is also the file name entry in column one, looking like picture 2.

I would like to apply the same thing to column 4, printing the name in every row. I don’t know if this information helps since getting the information for columns 1 and 4 is written in the same code block in section (5).

Could someone help me figure out how to solve this problem? I have been trying to implement some sort of “i++” in that section (5) of code…but have not been successful. Thank you for any suggestions!

[image]

[image]

**FULL CODE** *section (5) deals with the naming of the files in columns 1 and 4 of the masterfile.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Dim spl As Variant
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then

            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ";")

            v = spl(0)
            End If

            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ",")

            v = spl(0)
            End If


            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a way of figuring out the last used row at a time, you are very close to a solution. What you want to do is to write the `objFile.Name` not only to `StartSht.Cells(i, 1)`, but to `StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, 3), 1))`.

To break it down:

`StartSht.Range()` addresses a rectangular area in your Sheet `StartSht`. You specify this area by providing the corners: `StartSht.Cells(i, 1)` is the upper corner that you already know, `GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, 3)` gets you the last row of the data you just wrote in section (3) and (4). Thus, `StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, 3), 1)` finalizes your area and writes the value of `objFile.Name`.

You can then do the same thing with your copy-command.

Comment: Okay. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you for explaining what you mean. Where would I implement this? Because in order to use GetLastRowInColumn.. it would have to get that last row from column 2 or 3 and then print it to 1..since 1 contains information only in the first cell. @Verzweifler

Comment: Oh wait okay I understand what your line of code means now but still not sure where to implement it. I was trying to put in in replace of `StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name` in section 5 but that caused an error in section (10) function saying the GetLastRowInColumn line was out of range

Comment: I have tried creating another same function but replacing theWorksheet with StartSht ... but GetLastRowInColumn is still out of range and I cannot figure it out @Verzweifler

Comment: @Taylor: I'm sorry, I didn't see that the function `GetLastRowInColumn` requires a String as Column argument! In this case, replace `GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, 3)` with `GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C")`

Alternatively, you can use the `GetLastRowInSheet`-function and only pass `StartSht` as argument.

Comment: Okay, now the name prints in the first cell and last cell i want it to print in, but not all of the cells inbetween. Did I leave something out? @Verzweifler

Comment: Also could you explain what you mean about GetLastRowInSheet a little further? I'd like to know how to utilize that too for any future reference and for hopefully using it to do the same to column 4. Thank you!

Comment: This has two parts; I'll start with `GetLastRowInSheet`: The function utilizes the Cells.find()-function to find the last cell of the sheet, and then gets the `.row` of it. Personally, I find the `GetLastRowInColumn`-function more intuitive.

Please make sure you use the line `StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, 3), 1))` as it is, to avoid addressing two separate cells - the `Range()`-operator around the two inner cell addresses is important!